# Getting stdout from an executed application

Tags: c, linux, stdout, execvp

Does anyone know how to catch the output (I think its stdout) from `execvp` instead of the system printing it (in c on linux) in the terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`execvp` *replaces the current running process in memory*. There's no "catching" the output.

I suspect you're trying to run an external process from an existing process, and parse its output. For that you need to use `popen()` which does a `fork()` then an `exec()`, returning a `FILE *` to read (which will be the `stdout` of the process you just ran).

Answer (score 4):

I distrust `popen/pclose`, as I've worked on too many systems where `SIGCHLD` was handled ***slightly*** differently. And I distrust the `sh`-shell parsing used by `popen`, since I rarely use it.

The short 22-year-old O'Reilly book [***Using C on the UNIX System***, by Dave Curry](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780937175231.do) is still a ***very*** good reference for this sort of stuff.

Anyway, here is some code. It is a bit lengthy, as it parses the sample string `"/bin/ls /etc"` into the array `{"/bin/ls", "/etc", 0}`. But I find using the string format easier ***and*** shorter 98% of the time, although this example belies that.

This code generates a listing of `/etc.` You'll need to change some stuff like e.g. `NUMBER()` which is the same as`XtNumber()`.  And you'll need to decide whether it matches your handling of `SIGCHLD`.

```
int main(void) {  // list the files in /etc
   char buf[100];
   FILE *fp;
   int pid = spawnfp("/bin/ls /etc", &fp);
   while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp))
      printf("%s", buf);
   fclose(fp);                    // pclose() replacement
   kill(pid, SIGKILL);            // pclose() replacement
   return 0;
}
```

The subroutines here are:

```
static int spawnpipe(const char *argv[], int *fd) // popen() replacement
{
   int pid;
   int pipe_fds[2];

   if (pipe(pipe_fds) < 0)
      FatalError("pipe");

   switch ((pid = fork()))
   {
      case -1:
         FatalError("fork");
      case 0:                     // child
         close(1);
         close(2);
         dup(pipe_fds[0]);
         dup(pipe_fds[1]);
         close(pipe_fds[0]);
         close(pipe_fds[1]);

         execv(argv[0], (char * const *)argv);
         perror("execv");
         _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    // sic, not exit()
      default:
         *fd = pipe_fds[0];
         close(pipe_fds[1]);
         return pid;
   }
}
```

This converts an ascii string to an `argv` list, which is probably useless to you:

```
Bool convertStringToArgvList(char *p, const char **argv, int maxNumArgs)
{
   // Break up a string into tokens, on spaces, except that quoted bits, 
   // with single-quotes, are kept together, without the quotes. Such  
   // single-quotes cannot be escaped. A double-quote is just an ordinary char.
   // This is a *very* basic parsing, but ok for pre-programmed strings.
   int cnt = 0;
   while (*p)
   {
      while (*p && *p <= ' ')    // skip spaces
         p++;
      if (*p == '\'')            // single-quote block
      {
         if (cnt < maxNumArgs)
            argv[cnt++] = ++p;   // drop quote
         while (*p && *p != '\'')
            p++;
      }
      else if (*p)               // simple space-delineated token
      {
         if (cnt < maxNumArgs)
            argv[cnt++] = p;
         while (*p > ' ')
            p++;
      }
      if (*p)
         *p++ = 0;               // nul-terminate
   }
   if (cnt < maxNumArgs)
      argv[cnt++] = 0;
   return cnt <= maxNumArgs;     // check for too many tokens (unlikely)
}
```

This converts the argument string to tokens and, more importantly, the `fd` to an `fp`, since the OP requested `stdout`:

```
int spawnfp(const char *command, FILE **fpp)
{
   const char *argv[100];
   int fd, pid;
   if (!convertStringToArgvList(strdupa(command), argv, NUMBER(argv)))
      FatalError("spawnfp");
   pid = spawnpipe(argv, &fd);
   *fpp = fdopen(fd, "r");
   return pid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen), I think it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `popen` is what you want to use. Something like this...

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_BUFFER = 255;

int main()
{
        string cmd;
        cout << "enter cmd: ";
        cin >> cmd;
        cout << endl << "running " << cmd << "…" << endl;


        string stdout;
        char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
        FILE *stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
        while ( fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, stream) != NULL )
        stdout.append(buffer);
        pclose(stream);


        cout << endl << "output: " << endl << stdout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Well the cin will drop the arguments but if you cin them properly w/ getline, you popen can handle something "ls -latr".

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer, which gives `popen` a `execvp` style interface.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31063/popen-with-array-of-arguments